# Java Web Application HTTPS works only when -Djavax.net.debug=all is set

Tags: java, web, https, jetty

I have a Java jetty-based web application that I am migrating from HTTP to HTTPS.

I was experiencing difficulty connecting to the application over HTTPS - the request would just hang and eventually timeout.

I then set the JVM option -Djavax.net.debug=all to try and debug what was going on and to my surprise I was able to connect over HTTPS.

To make sure I was not going mad I then removed the option and once again could not connect over HTTPS.

This is very puzzling to me - I thought this option would just affect logging behavior, not actual application behavior. Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Was it a timeout or was the connection rejected? And you're sure that you have the valid HTTPS credentials that you're forwarding to the JVM?

Comment: Hi Vermillion, it is a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug with the version of jetty I was using (9.4.14.v20181114), upgrading to a newer version (9.4.15.v20190215) allowed me to connect without setting -Djavax.net.debug=all

It is still unclear to me why setting -Djavax.net.debug=all made it work.